# Creating multiple lists, putting inside another list, then sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to be able to:

- define a function that accepts two parameters. create two lists, one
  with names and another with grades.
- put the data from those two lists into a third list, with the grades 
  corresponding to the name that is in the same place in the first list. i.e: 
  have the same index value.
- then, I need to be able to sort that list in descending order by the
  grades.

This is all I have so far:

```
def gradeAvg(lst1,lst2):
    lst1 = ["Jo", "Ji", "Ja"]
    lst2 = [[90],[80],[70]]

    jo = lst1[0]
    ji = lst1[1]
    ja = lst1[2]

    jogr = str(lst2[0])
    jigr = str(lst2[1])
    jagr = str(lst2[2])


    lst3 = [[jo + jogr],[ji+jigr],[ja+jagr]]

    print(lst3)
```

which gives me this output:

```
[['Jo[90]'], ['Ji[80]'], ['Ja[70]']]
```

However, I need my output to be more similar to this:

```
Kim/98
Lib/96
Mar/95
Nat/92
Ophelia/90
Princ/89
Rhea/87
```

Is the way I created my lists "OK". And where do I go from here to sort the lists?

Comment: Wouldn't a dictionary be more suitable for your data or is this a list-specific assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"put the data from those two lists into a third list", that's what [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) does.

Step 3 is in the `reverse` parameter to [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
def gradeAvg(lst1,lst2):
    for a, b in sorted(zip(lst1, lst2), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
        print("{}/{}".format(a, b))

l1 = ['Kim', 'Lib', 'Mar', 'Nat', 'Ophelia', 'Princ' ,'Rhea']
l2 = [98, 96, 95, 92, 90, 89, 87]

gradeAvg(l1, l2)
```

output:

```
Kim/98
Lib/96
Mar/95
Nat/92
Ophelia/90
Princ/89
Rhea/87
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the way you created your list is not okay, what you want is actually create a list with the elements containing pairs of name and grade, like

```
[('mar', 95), ('Kim', 98) ...]
```

You can create this list manually or use built-in `zip` function

```
list3 = list(zip(list1, list2))
```

Then you can sort this list by providing a key function to the sort method on list

```
list3.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
```

Here I am sorting based on the grade notice I am returning `pair[1]` which is grade and `reverse=True` sorts in descending order.

Then you can simply iterate over `list3` and print:

```
for name, grade in list3:
    print('{}/{}'.format(name, grade))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(names,grades):
    return_list = []
    for i in range(0,len(names)):
        return_list.append( {names[i]:grades[i] }
    return_list = sorted(return_list, reverse=True)

    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        for key in a[i]:
            print str(key)+ '/'+str(a[i][key][0])
```